# Live streaming with player, AWS adobe media server (HLS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using Adobe Media Server 5.0 and try to do live streaming and using 
HLS player to render the video for testing. Below the link:
`https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/?src=http%3A%2F%2Fd32ng49n9bwcfu.cloudfront.net%2Fhls-live%2Flivepkgr%2F_definst_%2Fliveevent%2Flivestream.m3u8&enableStreaming=true&autoRecoverError=true&enableWorker=true&dumpfMP4=false&levelCapping=-1&defaultAudioCodec=undefined`

I also changed the `crossdomain.xml` for testing purpose:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

However the video is not running... can anyone enlighten me?